# Nginx different locations on one virtual host

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver

I have the following nginx config for my virtual host:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name myproject;

    location / {
        root /var/www/project1;
    }

    location /project2 {
        root /var/www/project2;
    }
}
```

But the web-server shows the following error:

```
location "/" is outside location "/project2"
```

I want to open first project via: `http://myproject` and second project via `http://myproject/project2`

What's wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one `root` in your `server{}` block. Read about the Nginx pitfalls here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls and look at the part about 'Root inside location block'.

Put the `root` outside the location blocks and set it to `/var/www`. Place your index file (and other files) for project1 in `/var/www`. Create a folder (`/var/www/project2`) and place the index etc. for project2 in this folder.

You can leave out the `location /project2 {}` part unless you want to specify some other settings for this project. If the settings are completely different from project1 I recommend moving all the stuff for project2 to another `server{}` block and specify its root and other settings there.